# How do I See if All of My Divs Have Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The JSFiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/jaredasch1/eayc4mj3/

I'm working on a game in JSFiddle, and I've come across a bit of a problem. Once all the boxes have the class ".on", I want to reset them all back to not having the class ".on" and perform a new action. However, I can't seem to find a way to do this. I've looked on here for answers but all the answers don't seem to work.

Here is the body of my HTML

```
    <body>
        <div id="button" class="on hover"></div>
    <br>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    <br>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    <br>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    <br>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    </body>
```

Here is my CSS

```
    .block {
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        border-radius:10px;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:#33CCFF;
    }
    #button {
        height:100px;
        width:410px;
        border-radius:10px;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:#FF6666;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .on {
        background-color:#D633FF;
    }
```

Finally, here is my JQuery/JavaScript

```
    var main = function () {
        $(".hover").mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.25);
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        });
        $(".hover").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
            $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
        });
        $(".block").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("on");
            $(this).prev().toggleClass("on");
            $(this).nextAll().eq(4).toggleClass("on");
            $(this).next().toggleClass("on");
            $(this).prevAll().eq(4).toggleClass("on");
        });
        $("#button").click(function () {
            $(".block").removeClass("on");
        });
        $(document).keydown(function (key) {
            if (event.which === 32) {
                $(".block").removeClass("on");
            }
        });
        };

    $(document).ready(main);
```

If anyone has any answers, please reply and I will gladly try them with an open mind. Thanks!

Comment: [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: `if ($('div').length === $('div.on').length)`?

Comment: Do you mean reset to not having the class ".on" ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not toggling away the .on class of the siblings with prev() and next() ?

Comment: When anything is purple, it has the on class (except the top button)

Comment: I can't seem to figure this out

Comment: Wait, what event triggers the check to see if all divs have the class ".on" ? I think my suggested code block is not being triggered with an event

Comment: Good idea. Let me try to fix that. Maybe check that when clicked

Comment: I don't think you have an event which triggers the check to see if all divs have class .on...I am going to edit my answer

Comment: Can you go onto the fiddle and insert it?

Comment: Just tried...not sure how to do this since my edits didn't save. I have to go get dinner for my wife...I hope this idea helps you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combined parts of each of the other answers to get this:

```
var checkAll = function() {
    var allDivs = $("div.block");
    var classedDivs = $("div.block.on");

    var allDivsHaveClass = (allDivs.length === classedDivs.length);

    if (allDivsHaveClass) {
        allDivs.removeClass("on");
    }
};
```

I added a call to this in the end of this function, and tada! it all works.

```
$(".block").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $(this).prev().toggleClass("on");
    $(this).nextAll().eq(4).toggleClass("on");
    $(this).next().toggleClass("on");
    $(this).prevAll().eq(4).toggleClass("on");
    checkAll();
});
```

Basically, everytime a block is clicked it checks if all the blocks are clicked.

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/eayc4mj3/7/).

Comment: Btw, I love this game. :) Super fun

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked Perfectly! Now I'm going to try to make the grid expand every time you win

Answer (score 4):

You can fetch all divs with jQuery, then fetch all divs with the `on` class on another call. You'll get two objects. Just compare their lengths ;)

```
var allDivs = $("div");
var classedDivs = $("div.on");

var allDivsHaveClass = (allDivs.length === classedDivs.length);
```

Then...

```
if (allDivsHaveClass) {
    allDivs.removeClass("on");
}
```

This will remove only the `on` class. If you would like to remove other classes as well, you may clear the class attribute of your div's, like this:

```
allDivs.attr("class", "");
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. For some reason it doesn't. Maybe JSFiddle Bug?

Comment: BTW the "nn", thing was a typo, meant to say "on"

Comment: @Jasch1 I've just edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't work. Can you try copying my code into JSFiddle or somewhere else to see if it's just a problem on my side?

Comment: any noticeable problems?

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the each() function:

```
var allDone = 'yes';
$("div.block").each(function (i) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("on")) allDone = 'no';
});

if (allDone === 'yes') $("div.block").removeClass("on");
```

But first you need an event to trigger this check. Suppose you want to check every 20 seconds to check if it is true that all div elements of class .block also have the class .on...

```
function checkOnClass() {
    var allDone = 'yes';
    $("div").each(function (i) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("on")) allDone = 'no';
    });

    if (allDone === 'yes') $("div").removeClass("on");

    setTimeout(function () {
        checkOnClass();
    }, 20000);
}


<body onload="checkOnClass()">
```

Comment: Pretty Sure JSFiddle Glitch, none of these reset the "on" class yet they all seem like they should

Comment: Please edit the question to include a link to the glitched JSFiddle. I suspect a typo in the fiddle rather than a glitch.

Comment: Any noticeable problems?

Comment: No, but try this caveman idea since you don't have too many divs....in the each() function insert alert($(this).attr("class")); See if the class .on is actually applied to all div elements and is alerted

Comment: Wait, nothing was alerted? Check Firebug to see if you have any errors. Alternatively, if you don't like Firebug, "Inspect Element" in Chrome or try this Lint program: http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php